# Get mapped delete proc to use changed Entity data

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to get a mapped delete procedure in EF (5.0, database first) to use updated properties in the entity as parameters.

The mapped procedure takes two parameters:

```
DeleteRow:
@Id : int          ->   (Key) Id : int32
@Modifiedby : char ->         Modifiedby : string
```

In the controller I want to change the `Modifiedby` value before the delete procedure is called.

```
Subscription subscription = context.Subscription.Find(id);
subscription.Modifiedby = "Test";
context.Subscription.Remove(subscription);
context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
context.SaveChanges();
```

However, when the procedure is called it is always the old value of `Modifiedby` that is passed to the delete procedure.

I don't want to do an update call to the database before deleting the entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving this by using none-tracked entities. Got the idea from this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/27/tip-9-deleting-an-object-without-retrieving-it.aspx

The `AsNoTracking()` method call is added and after the modifications the entities are attached to the context and then removed.

```
Subscription subscription = context.Subscription.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(i => i.RelatedEntity)
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.SubscriptionId == id);
subscription.Modifiedby = "TEST-Subcription";
subscription.RelatedEntity.ToList().ForEach(f => f.Modifiedby = "TEST_Related");
context.Subscription.Attach(subscription);
context.Subscription.Remove(subscription);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This allows the new `Modifiedby` values to be sent to the mapped delete procedure. I can also set new values for the related entities, which also have mapped procedures and for which cascade deletion is set.